# Django Looping through QuerySet Objects and adding temporary field to use for filtering

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm using DjangoRestFramework and have a queryset which returns objects for a generic ListAPIView. I want to loop through every object in the queryset and run the code below to calculate the distance value  using geopy distance.distance and then add it as a temporary field so i can later filter the queryset based on this new distance field.

Currently i have the following code, however it doesn't seem to save the new temporary field address.distance, i would like to return the new queryset while showing the new distance value for each object

in views.py:

```
class business_list(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BusinessSerializer
    @csrf_exempt
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        List all businesses.
        """
        queryset = Business.objects.all()
        distanceParam = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('distance', None)
        locationParam = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('location', None)
        if distanceParam is not None and locationParam is not None:
            for business in queryset:
                storelocations = ()
                for location in business.locations.all():
                    long = location.address.all()[:1].get().long
                    lat = location.address.all()[:1].get().lat
                    businessCoords = (lat, long)
                    testCoords = (40.795745, -73.948646)
                    address = location.address.all()[:1].get()
                    address_two = location.address.all()[:1].get()
                    address.distance = distance.distance(businessCoords, testCoords).miles
                    # my_obj_list = list(address, address_two)
                    # queryset = my_obj_list
            # wd = Business.objects.annotate(distance="lol")
            # queryset = wd
        return queryset
```

Comment: Is address a django model? It doesn't save your temporary field because you're not calling .save() anywhere. If it is a django model I would think the solution would be to just do address.save() after setting address.distance.

Comment: Address is indeed a django model, however calling .save() wouldn't accomplish the intended goal of only saving the data temporarily. I believe .save() would commit the changes to the database, that wouldn't work for the restful endpoint sort of use i need here.


I'm looking to hit an api endpoint with query parameters http://example.com/api/business?format=json&distance=test&location=test, and i would calculate the distance values for each unique search based on the parameters fed.

Comment: You should do distance calculation in you DB. Which DB are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgresql, should i be running raw sql query and then working with the queryset returned from that?

Comment: Continuing off my last answer, i'm trying to get the following raw sql query to work:`queryset = Address.objects.raw('SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM webapp_address HAVING distance < 25 ;')` however i'm having issues with `AS distance FROM webapp_address HAVING distance < 25 ` 

Django will throw an error : column "distance" does not exist, which i know it doesn't but then what's the correct syntax for filtering by a temporary distance value?